# can't find using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls namespace

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I tried every way to use `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;` but I didn't find any reference for that.

How can I use that namespace?

Comment: What type of project you create? It is .Net 4.0 Client Profile application, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your References for your project and ensure System.Web is in there. If not, Right click, Add Reference, .NET, and add System.Web

[image]

Comment: there's no reference which named system.web

Comment: Right click the References folder and "Add Reference"

Comment: there's nothing with this name in there

Comment: Go to the .NET tab, sort by Component Name.

Comment: yeah. that's right. but it only shows me system.web.applicationservices and system.web.services

Comment: OK. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741705/cannot-add-system-web-dll-reference

Answer (score 0):

you need to right-click the project -> properties -> then change the "Target framework" which will probably be ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" to just ".NET Framework 4".

Answer (score 0):

Browse to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll and pick it up from there as a reference