# Start and stop parsing of a string

Tags: c#-4.0

I grab a url and I want to parse and store two sections of the url

```
User/Confirmation?=QVNERkFTREY=&code=MTAvMjMvMjAxMyAxMjowMDowMCBBTQ==
```

So I want to start at `(Confirmation?=)` and stop at `(&)` and store the results

```
string = QVNERkFTREY
```

then for the second one I want to start at `(&code=)` and go to the end of the string and store that result

```
string = MTAvMjMvMjAxMyAxMjowMDowMCBBTQ==
```

I was have tried a few different things

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
string param1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("Confirmation?=");
string param2 = myUri.Query.Split();
```

Pretty sure I should be going a different route here but any help would be appreciate. I am going to continue to google search for now. I appreciate the help.

EDIT: I feel as though LINQ should be able to help me here..hmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring.aspx) rather than try to parse the URL myself.

```
String val = "User/Confirmation?=QVNERkFTREY=&code=MTAvMjMvMjAxMyAxMjowMDowMCBBTQ==";
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection parameters = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(val);
Console.Out.WriteLine(parameters[0]);  // QVNERkFTREY=
Console.Out.WriteLine(parameters.Get("code"); // MTAvMjMvMjAxMyAxMjowMDowMCBBTQ==
```

You will need to add System.Web.dll, which you can read about here: [Cannot add System.Web.dll reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741705/cannot-add-system-web-dll-reference)